# How can I do this in Xaml(something like auto margin?)

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, expression-blend

Say I have 2 textblocks beside each other

```
TextBlock 1 - Hi how are you?
TextBlock 2 - I am fine thank you
```

**Result**

```
 Hi how are you? I am fine thank you
```

Now say I want to hide textblock 1(dynamcially). I would still see Textblock 2 but before it would be a huge amount of space where textblock 1 would be.

**Result**

```
                 I am fine thank you
```

I would like to move textblock2 automatically over.

**Result**

```
 I am fine thank you
```

This would also be the similar case if I dynamically changed TextBlock1 to be a shorter string of text and had both of them side by side, there would be lots of black space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set column 0 's width to Auto, like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="textblock1" Text="Textblock1"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="textblock2" Text="Textblock2">  </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

For moving textblock2 into textblock1's location, you are looking for Visibility.Collapsed instead of Visibility.Hidden

For the auto width thing, you would want to define the Column width to be * instead of a fixed width.

Comment: My problem is not hiding it, My problem is once the TextBox is hidden my textbox2 does not move. I am doing this in Blend Expressions and when I drag the labels side beside a margin get set, so that probably is the reason but I don't know how to set it to auto or something like that.

Comment: What sort of layout are you using? A grid?  If so you need to define two columns, and put textblock1 in column 0 and textblock2 in column 1.  Set column 1's width to *.  Then, instead of 'hiding' textblock1, you 'collapse' it.  textblock2's column will then expand to fill the space left by textblock1.

Comment: I am not following I put both of them into the columns of my grid but I always just used "Visibility.Collapsed" in fact I can't see Visibility.Hidden. When I use Collapsed still not getting the result I want.Am I suppost to collapse the column?

Comment: What is the width on your column?  It should be something like -> <ColumnDefinition Width="*" /><ColumnDefinition Width="\*" />  You can also do <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />  You can also look at http://wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html for a reference.

Comment: This might help as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965292/how-can-you-get-a-xaml-textblock-to-collapse-when-it-contains-no-data